# How to filter through 3 sets data in the DB?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application that allows users to watch various clips, from different films. The admin is responsible for creating the Studio, in which the films, and clips are associated, as well as actually uploading the clips from the various films.

Now, I'd like to add the ability for the admin to choose a studio then a film, and then choose a clip and a date range, so that when they click "Filter" the admin will get statistics based on any given clip.

The statistics would ultimately show the user, the type of user account etc...

Here's an mockup to illustrate how it must work: [image: date-range]

Bare in mind, I already have the User, Studio, Film, and Clip data in the DB I'd just like to add this Filter functionality. If you can point me in the right direction of how this can be done, that would be great!!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where is the problem : is it a modelisation problem ? A controller problem ? A model problem ? A relational problem ?... Give more information and what you have currently tested.

Comment: for each model's controller you cans make an action that render json of his childs, then handle the request to fill the select tag

Comment: Thanks @knotito this is what I was looking for, care to provide an example of this? I'd be happy to provide any additional model/controller code if needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a solution if you use scaffold generated controllers

```
class StudioController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_studio, only: [:films...]
  ...
  def films
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: @studio.films.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

then set the route

```
resources :studio do
  member do
    get 'films'
  end
end
```

finally map events with javascript in your view

```
<script>
  $('#studio_select').change(function() {
    $.ajax({dataType: 'json', url: '/studios/' + $(this).val() + '/films.json'}).done(function(data) {
      $('#film_select').html('');
      $.each(data, function(id, elt) {
        $('#film_select').append('<option value="' + elt.id + '">' + elt.title + '</option>');
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

so on for child elements.
Not sure of the javascript part, but it should look like this...

Hope this helps :)